# Is there a way to optain categories created in a NodeRED Server?

Tags: node-red

Currently I have multiples customs categories installed in my NodeRED server, I am able to see in the browser, here is an screenshot:

[image: Installed categories]

I am looking for a way to access to those values using HTTP API (or any other way) from NodeRED, I have tried with the link http://localhost:1880/locales/editor?lng=en-US

[image: Default categories]

But it just returns the default categories not the custom categories that I have added.

Answer (score 1):

When the editor is opened in the browser, it loads all of the nodes into the palette.

When a node is loaded, it registers itself with the editor and tells it what category it belongs to. The editor then adds it to that category - creating the category if needed.

All of that is to say, the list of categories is dynamically generated purely within the editor.

The runtime side has no knowledge of the categories - they only exist within the browser. This means there is no API available for getting the list remotely.